# Limit of function with three variables

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

given is $f(x,y,z) = \frac{xy + yz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.
I want the limit for this function for $(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)$.

Since I haven't done this ($=$calculating a limit for a function with more than $1$ variable), I'm not sure what to do. But having taken a look at some specific examples I found on the internet, I tried doing this:

$f(x,y,0) = \frac{0}{x^2} \to 0$. Same for $f(x,0,z)$ and $f(0,y,z)$.
$f(x,x,0) = \frac{1}{2}$.
So since the limits are not the same, the whole function is not convergent.

I'm grateful for any kind of help!

Comment: I think you meant $f(x,0,0)=0/x^2$. Anyway, the limit doesn't exist exactly because of what you said. In order for the limit $(x,y,z)\rightarrow 0$ to exist, limits in any directions have to exist and coincide.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Just a second example; the function $f(x,y,z) = \frac{x^2-y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Can I say there's no limit just because of $f(x,0,0) = 1 \to 1$ and $f(0,y,0) = -1 \to -1$ isn't the same?

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would approach the problem. First I will check if the limit depends on how you get to $(0,0,0)$. To do this check, I will let $y=\alpha x$ and $z=\beta x$. The two constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ determine the direction of approach. The limit is
$$
\frac{xy + yz}{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \frac{\alpha + \alpha\beta}{1 + \alpha^2 + \beta^2}$$
Here $x^2$ cancels out. Clearly the limit depends on the direction, so the **limit does not exist.**

You can stop here.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "directio nof approach" ?

Comment: The path taken by $(x,y,z)$ as it tends to the limit $(0,0,0)$